# Getting value errorin LSTM model

Tags: python, sequence, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I am training a sequence to sequence model where training and target sets have equal dimensions. I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense,RNN,LSTM,Activation,Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
# Let us do for input data
data = pd.read_csv('E:\Final Work\yout1.csv') 
#print(data)
X = data[:16255]
X = np.array(X)
print(X[-1])
X1 = np.append(X,[1554.671208])
#print(X1)
print(len(X1))
XX = X1.tolist()
n = 16256
length = 254
samples = list()
for i in range(0,n,length):
sample = XX[i:i+length]
samples.append(sample)
#print(len(samples))
#print(samples)
traindata = np.array(samples)
traindata = traindata.reshape((len(samples), length, 1))
print(traindata.shape)
# Now do it for target data
data2 = pd.read_csv('E:\Final Work\counterforce.csv') 
#print(data)
X2 = data[:16255]
X2 = np.array(X2)
print(X2[-1])
X12 = np.append(X2,[1554.671208])
#print(X1)
#print(X12.shape)
XX2 = X12.tolist()
n = 16256
length = 254
target = list()
for i in range(0,n,length):
    sample2 = XX2[i:i+length]
    target.append(sample2)
#print(len(target))
#print(target)
traintarget = np.array(target)
traintarget = traintarget.reshape((len(target), length, 1))
print(traintarget.shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(3,input_shape=(254,1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(traindata,traintarget,batch_size=1,epochs=10,validation_split=0.2)
p = model.predict(traindata)
print(p)
```

However, am getting value error 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_24 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 254, 1)
On line 57 model.fit(traindata,traintarget,batch_size=1,epochs=10,validation_split=0.2)

I guess it has something to do with batch_size. But not sure

Comment: Can you show the output of model.summary() ? This way I can view the shapes of each layer.

Comment: The issue comes from the way you represent the target with the actual output, the model espected to have two dimensions (batch_size, n_possible_outputs), but instead you are giving it a One-hot encoding vector